# Javascript deny Videos loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

i want to deny the preloading of my videos on my page. I tried to implement the HTML5 Tag "Preload:"none"" but i cant do that, because i´m using a Videoslider in Wordpress. On my website [www.motivfilm.de](http://motivfilm.de) you can observe that the header video is loading pretty good, which i insert manuelly with HTML5 video tag. But the page cant stop loading because the video slider isnt fully load.
Thats the point why i search for a script to cancel the loading of the Videoslider while the Header video should load. I want that the video slider only loads when you click play the video manuelly. 
Is there a solution for my problem ? 
I tried to remove the SRC from the video slider and put the SRC in when you click play, but that didnt worked on the most browsers.

My actuall script look like this.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
//load background images first
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

$('body').waitForImages({
    waitForAll: true,
    finished: function() {
       // All images have loaded.
    }  
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//check mobile devices
function isMobile(){
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|blackberry|android|Kindle|htc|lg|midp|mmp|mobile|nokia|opera mini|palm|pocket|psp|sgh|smartphone|symbian|treo mini|Playstation Portable|SonyEricsson|Samsung|MobileExplorer|PalmSource|Benq|Windows Phone|Windows Mobile|IEMobile|Windows CE|Nintendo Wii)/i);
}
if(isMobile()){


}else {
   // stop video when scrolling down
var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("deny"),
fraction = 0.8;
function checkScroll() {

    

        var video = deny;

        var x = video.offsetLeft, y = video.offsetTop, w = video.offsetWidth, h = video.offsetHeight, r = x + w, //right
            b = y + h, //bottom
            visibleX, visibleY, visible;

            visibleX = Math.max(0, Math.min(w, window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth - x, r - window.pageXOffset));
            visibleY = Math.max(0, Math.min(h, window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - y, b - window.pageYOffset));

            visible = visibleX * visibleY / (w * h);

            if (visible > fraction) {
                video.play();
            } else {
                video.pause();
            }

    

}

window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', checkScroll, false)
}
</script>
 
<html>
    <video class="deny" id="deny" poster="wp-content/uploads/2016/02/LoadingGif.gif" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay loop="loop" preload="none" autobuffer>
        <source src="wp-content/uploads/2016/02/ShortReel20.16_Mute.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

</html>
```

Please help me!
Thank you